# Android bitmap recycle: need to set null?

Tags: android, android-bitmap, recycle

Is it necessary to set a `Bitmap` to `null` after recycling it, so that its memory can be freed?

In the following code:

```
private static Bitmap bmpConcatHV() {
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resId);
    Bitmap bmp2 = concatVertically(bmp, bmp);
    bmp.recycle();
    bmp = null;
    Bitmap bmp3 = concatHorizontally(bmp2, bmp2);
    bmp2.recycle();
    bmp2 = null;
    return bmp3;
}
```

There are `Lint` warnings:

> The value null assigned to 'bmp' is never used
>
> The value null assigned to 'bmp2' is never used

Answer (score 1):

Both `bmp` and `bmp2` are local variables, so no.

Comment: Maybe the memory of bmp1 should be freed before memory for bmp3 is allocated.

Comment: Very good point. In this case, you also call `recycle`, which as far as I understand the documentation will ensure that the internal image data can be garbage-collected assuming no other references to the internal image data. But still.

Comment: I guess I might have answered a different question than the one you asked; the one I thought about was reg. ensuring that `bmp` and `bmp2` are eventually garbage collected, which they will be since they are local variables (also that the documentation for `Bitmap` describes that they do not need to be released manually as such, since garbage collection will also release the internal parts). But you may have (wisely) worried more about releasing early, since images can take up lots of memory and memory is generally limited on Android.

Comment: Releasing early is handled by your calls to `recycle`, the references in the local variables will not hinder the garbage collection of the internal image data.

Answer (score 0):

```
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resId);
```

bitmap has two part of information when loaded into memory 
1- information about bitmap ==> exists in java used memory
2- information about pixels of bitmap (byte of array) ==>exists in c++ used memory

Bitmap.recycle() is used to free the memory of C++.
Garbage Collection  will collection the part of java and the memory

Garbage Collection work when need memory but i need to use this reference now so will use

```
bmp = null; here i handle the part of java and be safe to make it null
```

Comment: In https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/7f9f99ea11051614a7727dfb9f9578b518e76e3c/graphics/java/android/graphics/Bitmap.java#177 , it seems that there is both a Java buffer for the image data as well as a native buffer, and that `recycle` deals with both. But good point reg. the native part.

Comment: I would also say that `recycle` is used to free the memory earlier than otherwise, since the documentation describes that it does not need to be called as such.